# function template by value and by reference difference

Tags: c++, reference, temporary-objects

I am following this tutorial - http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/132-function-template-instances/

```
// passing all parameters by references
template <typename T1, typename T2>
const T2& add_two_objects(const T1& x,const T2& y) {
        return x+y;
};

int main() {
    using std::cout;
    int x(0),y(0);
    std::cout << "Please enter number 1" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "Please enter number 2" << std::endl;
    std::cin >> y;
    cout<< "sum of two integers is " << add_two_objects(x,y+1.2)    << '\n';
    cout<< "sum of two double is " << add_two_objects(x,y+2.52424324) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles fine, but at the run time, I always get a segmentation fault. However if I change the template to pass by value, then everything works.

```
// passing all parameters by value
template <typename T1, typename T2>
const T2 add_two_objects(const T1 x,const T2 y) {
        return x+y;
};
```

Can anyone please explain?

Comment: You can't return a reference to a temporary. But this is pretty pointless code, and quite poorly written. Maybe you should find a different tutorial?

Comment: @CodyGray at least the turial has a `using std::cout` instead of `using namespace std;`

Comment: I modfied the tutorial examples to try complexer things ( to understand of course )  The tutorial I think is quite good.

Answer (score 6):

This

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
const T2& add_two_objects(const T1& x, const T2& y) {
        return x+y;
};
```

returns a reference to a temporary. Make the return a value

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
T2 add_two_objects(const T1& x, const T2& y) {
        return x+y;
};
```

and you should be fine.

Btw, it's not clear that returning a `T2` is the best thing to do here. Consider for example the case `T1=size_t` and `T2=char`. Better to return the type that the operation `x+y` actually generates

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto add_two_objects(const T1& x, const T2& y)
-> decltype(x+y)
{
    return x+y;
};
```

------edit-----

You **must not return a reference to a temporary object**. It's a ***BUG***. If you want a bug, go for it. And you should not use poor tutorials. There are situations when you want/should return a reference, but this is not one of them. These are when the reference is to an object that will not be destroyed (or go out of scope) when returning form the function (as all automatic and temporary variables will).

Comment: but I would like to return a reference and not the value as suggested by your first solution. Does that mean that the tutorial code is wrong?

Comment: @infoclogged you would like to return a reference to what? A reference to a variable in the scope of the method is useless outside of the scope of the method

Comment: Okay, I have understood now. If I instantiate a static object, then the reference is no more pointing to a temporary object. So instead of returning (x+y) , I could declare  a static variable ( static T2 z; ) in the function template, and then return the reference ( z = x+y; return z ; ). ofcourse this is not a real code, but just to understand the basics.

Answer (score 1):

To make it more clear let's wrap the integers in structures.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    A( int x ) : x( x ) {}
    ~A() { std::cout << "[A::~A() is called for x = " << x << ']' << std::endl; }
    int x;
};

A operator +( const A &lhs, const A &rhs )
{
    return A( lhs.x + rhs.x );
}

std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const A &a )
{
    return os << a.x;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
const T2& add_two_objects(const T1& x,const T2& y) {
        return x+y;
};

int main() 
{
    std::cout<< "sum of two integers is " << add_two_objects( A( 1 ), A( 2 ) ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
prog.cc:22:18: warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
         return x+y;
                  ^
sum of two integers is [A::~A() is called for x = 3]
Segmentation fault
```

First of all the compiler warns that the function returns reference to a temporary value. That is after exiting the function the temporary object will be destroyed and this output

```
[A::~A() is called for x = 3]
```

confirms this.

As result the reference will be invalid and the program has undefined behavior.

In fact you can imagine the program logic the following way

```
int main() 
{
    const A &r = add_two_objects( A( 1 ), A( 2 ) );
    std::cout<< "sum of two integers is " << r << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output looks almost similar as in the above program

```
prog.cc:22:18: warning: returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr]
         return x+y;
                  ^
[A::~A() is called for x = 3]
[A::~A() is called for x = 1]
[A::~A() is called for x = 2]
Segmentation fault
```

That is the reference becomes invalid.

If to remove the reference in the function declaration

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
const T2/*&*/ add_two_objects(const T1& x,const T2& y) {
        return x+y;
};
```

then the program output might look like

```
sum of two integers is 3
[A::~A() is called for x = 3]
[A::~A() is called for x = 1]
[A::~A() is called for x = 2]
```

Comment: is there any particular reason that there is a warning for a struct, but not for `int`s?

Comment: @tobi303 The reason can be that the structure has a constructor and destructor.